# .ht access not working on Amazon linux server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, popstate

I've been working on a project that uses pushstate to manage site navigation. The project is currently hosted on a Godaddy shared hosting account and i've just setup an Amazon EC2 Linux server with HTTPD and have transfered the files across to the new server. I had to add a .htaccess file to help with the pushstate navigation so that it does not 404 when I try going to http://example.com/page1 for example.

When I try and access a page like http://example.com/page1 on the godaddy server it behaves as it should - it does not try and access the actual page but instead uses the root page and appends url path /page1 and my javascript takes care of visually showing page1's content. However, on the Amazon server it is taking me to a 404 page. I'm fairly new to .htaccess and push state so I had to go off what I could find on stack overflow to help me get this working (on the Godaddy server at least). Here's the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.html?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Not sure if I have used the correct approach nor why one server would give me a different result to the other?

Thanks

**EDIT**

So I have already set the allowOveride to all in my httpd.conf file as per below:

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Worth noting here i'm using HTTPD rather than Apache2 - i'm not sure if this could make a difference or not but seems to be the same procedure. I also restarted the server using `sudo service httpd restart` but it's still the same result. I did try the vhost option and while I can't remember exactly what I wrote for it I had it apply to */80 so i'm fairly sure it was written correctly.

Is there any other steps I can take to debug this further and try pin point exactly where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your apache2 configuration (**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**) for the setting bellow:

```
<Directory "/">
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

That won't allow the server settings to be overwritten by custom settings in the .htaccess file. So if you find that in your apache2 configuration you have 2 options:

1) Replace it with `AllowOverride All`, save the config and restart the apache2 service (applies server wide)

2) Leave it as it and add `AllowOverride All` strictly to the vhost configuration for your site (applies only for the vhost where it's added).

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer Bogdan, I just updated my question, please take a look

Comment: apache webserver is as apache2 under ubuntu/debian (as httpd on CentOS distros). I would check /var/log/httpd/error_log to see if there are any entries there that might offer aditional info about your issue or any specific vhost access/error log files

Comment: The error i'm getting in the error log is File does not exist: /var/www/html/site-feedback which to me suggests either the .htaccess file is not being picked up or the server has not allowed override..